# Android location app freezing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-location

I'm developing a simple "Check-In" app and I'm facing some troubles.

When I tap a ImageButton to get the location, my Logcat starts to response:

```
GC_EXPLICIT freed 365K, 18% free 14183K/17256K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 24ms 
to [...]
GC_EXPLICIT freed 137K, 1% free 17871K/18044K, paused 2ms+16ms, total 63ms
```

and the app freezes.
I reduced the lag changing RelativeLayout to LinearLayout, but the problem persists.
*PS: Running on Moto G (Motorola XT1033)
Code:

//MyLocationListener

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // in Meters
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 5000; // in Milliseconds
private LocationManager locationManager;

public MyLocationListener(LocationManager locationManager) {
    this.locationManager = locationManager;
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
            MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
            new MyLocationListener(locationManager)
    );

}

public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {


}

public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {


}

public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {


}

}
```

//CheckInActivity

```
public class CheckInActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
private LocationManager locationManager;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkin);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
    sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String truck = sharedPref.getString("name", "");

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) != null) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new MyLocationListener(locationManager));
    } else if (locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) != null) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new MyLocationListener(locationManager));
    } else {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new MyLocationListener(locationManager));
    }

    EditText folk = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.folkName);
    folk.setText(truck);
}

public void setLocation(View view) {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CheckInActivity.this);
    final EditText addressInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.addressInput);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Obtendo endereço atual…");
    progressDialog.show();

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Location>(){

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        protected Location doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            android.location.Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if ( location == null )
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if ( location == null )
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);


            System.out.println(location);

            if(location != null){
                double x = location.getLatitude();
                double y = location.getLongitude();


                final Location finalLocation = location;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        double x = finalLocation.getLatitude();
                        double y = finalLocation.getLongitude();
                        String x_val = String.valueOf(x);
                        TextView lat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lat);
                        lat.setText(x_val);

                        String y_val = String.valueOf(y);
                        TextView lon = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lon);
                        lon.setText(y_val);
                    }
                });
                System.out.println(x);
                System.out.println(y);

                try{
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(CheckInActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
                    final StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

                    if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
                        Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);

                        String cidade = returnAddress.getAdminArea();
                        String endereco = returnAddress.getAddressLine(0);
                        str.append(endereco).append(" - ").append(cidade);


                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                addressInput.setText(str);
                            }
                        });

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(CheckInActivity.this,
                                "geocoder not present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return location;
        }
    }.execute();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is here:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
            MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
            new MyLocationListener(locationManager)
    );
}
```

Every time you get a location update you're registering a new location listener, so the next time you will get two location updates and register two more location listeners, then four, then 8, then the system grinds to a halt.

Comment: Using your answer as base I just put some value in:
    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0;

now with 50 meters, the listener doesn't die on looping.